# Drilldown with Hyperlink support in React Highcharts barcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am following the below reference to create a column(bar) chart using React Highcharts with drill-down support.
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/

Example:

```
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
`;`
```

However, I need to call an external URL by clicking the Bar Chart or the Text on the X-axis. (Customised Hyperlink for each plotted value)
I am open to using any other charting library also which supports the same.

Tried the drill-down functionality which is available in the React highcharts library under "Column" chart. Also tried chart.js. But didn't work.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure if I understood what the problem is. You want to get rid of the hyperlink? Or drilldown doesn't work for you in React? Could you elaborate? For now here's a column drilldown demo in React: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rhygec?file=index.html,index.js